# How does typedef work in place of struct/class for Procedural c++?

Tags: c++, class, struct, typedef, procedural

I have to build a program(Procedural C++) that has two data types. One called Elem that is an element of a vector(single dimensional array). and One called Vector that contains an unsigned int for the size of the array and also the array of Elem's itself. I can't seem to figure out the correct way to structure these so that they work as I have never done anything with procedural c++ before.

This is what I have

```
typedef Elem {
    float Element;
}

typedef Vector {
    unsigned int size = 0;
    Elem* Array = new array[];
}
```

but I'm getting this error

```
C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
typedef Elem {
~~~~~~~ ^
```

and also

```
error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef Elem {
            ^
```

I'm at a loss here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider a `typedef` as a synonym for a longer expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say

```
typdef Elem {
...
};
```

The correct way is

```
struct Elem {
...
};
```

Note also the semicolon `;` at the end of the declaration.

See also [Class declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) for some small examples.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't realize struct was still available to procedural.. I feel dumb now..

Comment: you should add typedef in the correct way because the op wants it

Comment: It doesn't matter how you use C++, the basic construct is available nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef float Elem;

struct Vector {
    unsigned int size;
    Elem* Array;
};
```

You may define a full-fledged Vector class with constructor, destructor, copy semantic, etc. Or just use `std::vector<Elem>`.

---

You might be confused by C, in which a common idiom is:

```
typedef struct tagVector {
    ...
} Vector;
```

But this verbose syntax is unnecessary in C++.